# Find all files with .md extension and execute a command with the file and generate a new file with a name generated through the the md file name

Tags: html, linux, shell, sh, markdown

I'm trying to write a shell script to recursively find all files under a directory with the extension .md and execute a command with the .md file and generated new file with the same name but a different extension.

below is the command I'm having but its actually appending the .html to the file instead of replacing .md with .html

> find . -name '*.md' -exec markdown-html {} -s
>   resources/styles/common-custom.css -o {}.html \;

the above command generates a new file "home.md.html" from "home.md" but i want the .md removed. tried different solutions but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to write a small script here, I have given the description how it is going to work, please refer to the comments in the below codes:-

1. First create a shell script file like `convertTohtml.sh` and add below codes in it

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   find . -name '*.md' > filelist.dat 
   # list down all the file in a temp file

   while read file
   do
       html_file=$( echo "$file" | sed -e 's/\.md//g')
       # the above command will store 'home.md' as 'home' to variable 'html_file'
       #hence '$html_file.html' equal to 'home.html'

       markdown-html $file -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o $html_file.html 

   done <  filelist.dat
   # with while loop read each line from the file. Here each line is a locatin of .md file 

   rm filelist.dat
   #delete the temporary file finally
   ```
2. provide execute permission to your script file like below:-

   ```
   chmod 777 convertTohtml.sh
   ```
3. Now execute the file:-

   ```
   ./convertTohtml.sh
   ```

Comment: Hi, I dont want to delete the md files. I just want to generate a .html file using md files

Comment: what this command do? `markdown-html` Also what do you mean by this `the above command generates a new file "home.md.html" from "home.md" but i want the .md removed. tried different solutions but didn't work`? I thought you want to remove .md after creating html from it.

Comment: "markdown-html {} -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o {}.html" command is supposed to generate a html file using md file. what my problem was that the above command generates the html file as "home.md.html" but I want it like "home.html". so at the and all .md files will have its corresponding html file like "home.md" & home.html

Comment: You did not understand what actually I am asking. whether this command `markdown-html ` generate a new html file? Is `-s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o` is command line parameter?

Comment: yes "markdown-html" is a command that is used to convert md to html files

Comment: Your this command `find . -name '*.md' -exec markdown-html {} -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o {}.html \;`  is working like  markdown-html test.md -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o test.md.html  that's it.

Comment: So every thing fine. It is executing perfectly and creating a html from each md file. Now what is your issue here? If you now want source file to be remove you have to remove it.

Comment: Please look at my above comment -> what my problem was that the above command generates the html file as "home.md.html" but I want it like "home.html". so at the and all .md files will have its corresponding html file like "home.md" & home.html

Comment: If you want when your command create a html file at the same time it should remove the original file you have to contact the team who has develop the `markdown-html `.

Comment: @RoHaN, I have modified my answer. It will work for you. Let me know if you need any more assistance.

Comment: Please use my latest answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is generating what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the output of find multiple times you could try something like this:

```
find . -name "*.md" -exec sh -c "echo {} && touch {}.foo" \;
```

Notice the:

```
sh -c "echo {} && touch {}.foo"
```

The `sh -c` will run commands read from the string, then the `{}` will be replaced with the find output, in this example is first doing an `echo {}` and if that succeeds `&&` it will then `touch {}.foo`, in your case this could be like:

```
find . -name "*.md" -exec sh -c "markdown-html {} -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o {}.html" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script will work to solve the extension problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.md' > filelist.dat 
# list down all the file in a temp file
while read file
do
    file=`echo ${file%.md}`
    #get the filename witout extension

    markdown-html $file -s resources/styles/common-custom.css -o $file.html 

done <  filelist.dat
# with while loop read each line from the file. Here each line is a locatin of .md file 

rm filelist.dat
#delete the temporary file finally
```